# "Show" function issue in Matplotlib on Sublime REPL

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3

I've strange problem  when trying draw a plot, from
Sublime Text 3 Repl.
When I'm executing code below, nothing happened. REPL not reacting anymore for any commands:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,4,5])
plt.show()   # After hit enter nothing happened
```

However when Im executing this code, plot is displaying:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1,2,4,5]) # plot is displaying on this command
```

I've tested first code on python interpreter and windows  cmd, and its working in Sublime REPL not.

I'm using Python 3.4.1 and last build of ST3

Anyone have similar problem and can help?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem in the Sublime text 2 REPL.